# how to change a website available only for admin

Tags: .htaccess

i have a website that need to be unavailable for public.
I cannot test my website locally because lot of contents are depend on databases and images.

At present i am using **.htaccess**  to deny all the people,bots and allow my ip address to use the site. What happens i have a **dial-up ADSL modem** and my ISP connection is frequently disconnecting. So i need to change the allowed IP address in htaccess frequently.This is terrible.

Is there any other way to overcome this situation. I saw an article to make the site password protected. is it okay or what should i do to overcome this terrible scenario.
Thanks

Comment: access rights of the files? make them have read write access only to the user you want ... if you are in a unix like systems `cd doc_root;chown -R og= *` ... it will turn off any access to the files and dirs by others and group users

Comment: Thanks.I have linux godaddy hosting plan.I don't have shell access.

Comment: i have no idea about godaddy ... you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, password protecting is fine. Follow this guide: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

You need to create an htpasswd file, essentially the file that holds your username and password. If you don't have shell access on your hosting plan, you can go to an [online generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) and create the file locally and upload it to your hosting site (don't put it in your document root).

Then add this to your htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
Require valid-user
```

You can also whitelist IPs like you did before but you need to add this line:

```
Satisfy Any
```

So that your `Allow from 123.45.67.89` lines is sufficient and don't need to log in from that IP.

Comment: great thanks i will check this.one quick question.is this method okay for security of my website?

Comment: @vinu what do you mean by **"okay for security of my website"**?

Comment: I mean is there any security issues with this method.Is there any chance to hack my website?

Comment: @vinu the only real issue here is if it's not encrypted, someone can read the `Authorization` header and use it to gain access. Putting your website on SSL (https://) fixes that. You can also switch to using DIGEST authentication which is a little more strict (change the `Basic` to `Digest` and use a htdigest generator instead of htpasswd)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.That did the trick.Now everything is okay.